# url-mapping to compiled jsp (servlet) not working

Tags: jsp, tomcat, url-mapping

I have written a simple web app directly in the webapp directory of Tomcat and accessed the hello.jsp file through the localhost url. What I want to do now is to do a url-mapping to the servlet class that's compiled in the previous step. My web.xml code is as follows:

I want to be able to point to the url ending in "/hi" and have the compiled jsp run. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.hello_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hi</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Presently, when I try to reach it from my the specified url-pattern, I get this stack trace:

```
type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class org.apache.jsp.hello_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.apache.jsp.hello_jsp
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.hello_jsp
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed not right. You need to use `<jsp-file>` instead of `<servlet-class>`. After all, you've there in the source code just a JSP file, not a servlet class.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hi</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/hello.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hi</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```